# How to provide custom cost function for robustfit or fitlm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

If I know right- for trying to fit a model; some kind of iterative algorithm is used where the goal is to minimize a cost function (e.g. OLS, MSE, RMSE, MMSE).

I know the `robustfit()` method do the fitting for a regression model using OLS (Ordinary least squares) cost function and then performs an additional weighted regression to provide the final model. Also, I think `fitlm()` uses RMSE as the cost function.

My first query is: in Matlab, whether the cost function and weight function are same or not.
Also, how to provide my custom cost function (e.g. MSE) while letting MATLAB do the fitting?

I came to know that, `robustfit()` can take additional/[custom weight function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html#f2485578). But again I am confused will that be treated as cost function? Or I need to use some other kind of argument for providing my custom cost function?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, the cost function is the function you want to minimize to find the correct coefficients of your predictor. For example, a cost function could be `cost(a) = sqrt(mean((a).^2));`, `a` usually being `y - y_est`.

In another side, the weight function, regarding to Robust Regression, is a way to give less influence or to remove accidental measurements for the algorithm. If you look at the shape of a weight function:

[image: weight]

You will see that the further residuals are from zero, the less they are taken in account (sometimes even completely removed) . This is a way to avoid mistakes due to outliers.

The way the function estimates error is not open to custom, only the weight function is.